# Use Touchscreen in freya

Tags: release-freya, touchscreen

Can laptop touchscreen be used? The main reason i installed elementary to try linux is that i read touchscreen could be activated on ubuntu. I also read a question for old elementary os about this answerred positively. Can anyone guide this noob please!! I tried searching for it but couldn't find any resource for freya. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try booting from the live USB

Comment: I already installed it on my pc. I want to use it as my regular os. I hate windows and don't have enough money for a macbook.

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't work out: https://old.elementary.io/answers/is-my-touchscreen-laptop-supported

It's quite old so i guessed it won't work but tried anyway and failed.

Comment: First install freya and then install kernel 4.4. Kernel 4.4 is the new LTS kernel which is used in Ubuntu 16.04 but it can also be used in 14.04 (freya).The guide you are reading is outdated